# Python NameError when using an imported function

Tags: python, function, import, nameerror

When I import and use a function in a python(2.6.5) program, I get an error:

```
from Localization import MSGR

title = Localization.MSGR("Logfile from Ctf2Rrl.")
```

> NameError: global name 'Localization' is not defined

Could you please explain why?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you import your method like this, you can user `MSGR` but not `Localization.MSGR` :)

If you want to use `Localization.MSGR`, you can just `import Localization`

Answer (score 2):

The import statement of the form:

```
from foo import bar
```

Doesn't introduce the module name (`foo`) from which the imports (`bar`) are taken into the module namespace.

Only the name `bar` is defined, not the module from which you imported `bar.